# Magento URL Rewrite for custom template for seo friendly urls

Tags: magento-1.7, php, htaccess

i am working on a website omegabanners.com and i have create the some custom template for designing tool. the product is saving into the database. when someone open the product the url shows http://www.omegabanners.com/fullcolorbanner?productId=1277

This kinds of url is not good for SEO i need SEO friendly URL for my website. like http://www.omegabanners.com/category/product-name

can anyone help me how can i do that either on template code or using the htaccess.

please check on specific url

[1]omegabanners.com/doublesidedbanner?proId=1239
[2]omegabanners.com/banner-stands/retractable-banner-stands/retractable-banner-stand-47x78.html
[3]omegabanners.com/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/1239/s/retractable-banner-stand-47x78/

These are the specific url for one product. my currently url show like url [1]
but i need it to shows like [2]. how i can i show it like [2]

and when i try to fetch the url magento ass [2] the desgin goes totally disturb i know the is the template reason..

Answer (score 2):

Try following this link for custom URL rewrites:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/seo/how_to_work_with_magento_url_rewrite_rules

Comment: Hi url is setup properly. but not redirect on right position.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by not redirect on right position?  Can you please place a screen capture of the custom URL rewrite configuration ?

Comment: my oriegnal product is http://www.omegabanners.com/doublesidedbanner?proId=1239 and the url key is retractable-banner-stand-47x78.html i need to call the product as http://www.omegabanners.com/banner-stands/retractable-banner-stands/retractable-banner-stand-47x78.html but the total design goes off. i dont understand what is the solution is for. and how can i add the screenshot?

Comment: Go to catalog->URL Rewrite Management check what is the ID Path, Request Path and Target Path for this product ?

Comment: ID path 95920300_1398029076 request path retractable-banner-stand-33x78.html target path retractable-banner-stand-47x78.html and redirect 301 temperory

Comment: Open up this Rule and Delete it.
Then go back to the URL Rewrite Management Page->Add URL Rewrite.
Create URL Rewrite-> Select Custom
Select the Store name which you want this URL rewrite.
ID Path: 95920300_1398029076
Request Path: banner-stands/retractable-banner-stand-33x78.html
Target Path: doublesidedbanner?proId=1239